# Cycles render showing path tracing tile only and not samples

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I can tell by the time taken that my samples render and preview values are factoring in, but it does not show while rendering. Instead it displays the path tracing tile value which is set to 135 somehow (how is that calculated). My square samples is turned off too. How do i get it to show me samples count while its rendering?

[image: Render Screenshot]

[image: Output settings]